# Jquery not working on mobile device ( works on responsive desktop version )

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have the following script which does not work on my mobile phone.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.qtyplus' , function(e) {
      var mainProductIDPlus = $(this).attr('data-itemid');
      if ( $( this ).hasClass( "qtyplushide" )) {
            console.log("hiding");
            $(this).closest(".size-selector-wrapper-plus").addClass('hidden');
            $(this).closest(".size-selector-wrapper-plus").css("zIndex", "0");
            var currentMainVal = parseInt($(this).parent('.size-selector-wrapper').siblings('.meal-row-quantity-collection').find('input').val());
            $(this).parent('.size-selector-wrapper').siblings('.meal-row-quantity-collection').find('input').val(CurrentMainVal+1);

          }
    });
```

It gets to the console.log statement, which indicates the if statement is true, it will print "hiding" however the element does not disappear ( z index 0 ) only on my mobile device(I Phone Safari browser), it functions properly on desktop and responsive desktop windows.

Are any of the commands used not compatible on mobile?

EDIT : While debugging I  found the step that stops my script on mobile device

```
                $(this).closest(".size-selector-wrapper-plus").addClass('hidden');
```

This line does not generate an error, however it immediately exits the script and does not allow the script to go farther ( hide the element )

Comment: setting z-index to zero doesn't hide an element.

Comment: does mobile have the concept of "click"? Isn't it on touch?

Comment: Try changing "zIndex" to "z-index", I'm surprised that CSS would work anywhere to begin with. We would need to see what your CSS is doing if that doesn't work

Comment: @DanielBeck I am researching more and I believe the issue is with the z-index as well.  Any suggestions to have the element go back to the bottom?

Comment: If you're trying to hide an element, use `display:none`. I don't know why you're fiddling with the z-index at all.

Comment: z-index of 0 will not hide an element. It just puts it at the 0 position in the stacking order. Also, in order for z-index to work, the element has to be set to either "relative" or "absolute".

Comment: Stu Furlong, that is not correct. He is using the correct syntax for zIndex already. jQuery uses zIndex, not z-index when using the CSS() method.

Comment: You're adding a hidden class to the element as well, does that CSS have any media queries attached to it that might only be hiding the element at desktop sizes?

Comment: @Korgrue setting position is one way to trigger a stacking context, but [it's not the _only_ way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). Also, jQuery accepts both "z-index" and "zIndex".

Comment: @Korgrue, thanks for the info.. never knew that! I almost always avoid setting CSS through JS like this

Comment: @StuFurlong the hidden element seems to be working, it works on responsive sized windows ( 320 px ) however just on my mobile device it doesnt lol so strange...

Comment: >setting position is one way to trigger a stacking context, but it's not the only way.

He has not employed a different way. He is setting the stacking order implicitly in his jQuery function. For this to work, that element must be set to either display:relative, or display:absolute. z index does not work on the default display type.

Comment: @Korgrue the position of the element is absolute.

Comment: @Korgrue, you're spreading misinformation. `absolute` and `relative` are not the only values for `position` that work with `z-index` nor is `z-index` exclusive to `position`. Get your facts straight.

Comment: There has to be a reason why it is only not working on mobile device and is working on all desktop browsers even when resized.

Comment: At this point it's tough to narrow down, it could be for a number of reasons. This code above from what I see shouldn't cause issues on a mobile device, so it could either be a JS error from code outside of this, or something in the CSS. I would add display none on your hidden class and make sure it works at mobile sizes. If it still doesn't work on your phone from there, then I'd start debugging your JS

Comment: Also, maybe double check it's not related to any kind of caching!

Comment: André Dion - My bad, Fixed also works - however my statement stands as accurate. z-index does not work on the default positioning.

Comment: @AndréDion updated question with helpful information, if you guys could take a look it would be a huge help!

Comment: Can you try chaining those? addClass('hidden').css('zIndex','0'); Or instead of applying the css via jquery add another class with that z-index, or apply the z-index to the hidden class if possible.